# Regex using Notepad++ to add space before a capital letter

Tags: regex, notepad++, capitalization

I have looked around and found good answers but none work with notepad++, most are for java and php.  I have found the search strings below but obviously I'm a noob with regex as i don't know what open/close tags are proper in notepad++.

I would like to add a space before each capital letter.

Example:

StackOverflowKegger

becomes

Stack Overflow Kegger

This is what i have found.

Find: `[a-z]+[A-Z]+`
Replace:  `$1`  (there is a space before the $)

Find:

```
(?<!^)((?<![:upper:])[:upper:]|[:upper:](?![:upper:]))

("(\\p{Ll})(\\p{Lu})","$1 $2")

(?!^)(?=[A-Z])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

Search string: `(.)([A-Z])`
Replacement: `\1 \2`

This doesn't insert spaces before capitals that are the first letter on their line.

Comment: Since Notepad++ does not support negative lookbehind for regexes, I guess this solution is as good as it can get.

Comment: Also, remember to check "Match case" in Notepad++ to make the regex case sensitive.

Comment: Definitely remember to check "Match case" in Notepad++ to make the regex case sensitive. Like @iDifferent says.

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++, do a search-n-Replace (ctrl+h), in 'find what' input  '([a-z])([A-Z])' without single quotes.  in 'Replace with' input '\1 \2'  without quotes.

Select radio button 'Regular Expression' and make sure you Check 'Match Case' checkbox. Now find next and keep replacing.   it will convert camel or Pascal case strings into words with a space before every capital letter except the first.

Hope it is helpful. I just used it with one of my tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Find what: `.\K([A-Z])`
Replace with:  `$1`   a `space`  before `$1`
Note!!!!!!  Must to check `match-case`  see in attached photo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find: ^([A-Z])

Replace: \1

this will add a space to the first uppercase character in notepad++ 
Make sure you put the space before the \1 in the replace section.

WABET : <-from
 WABET : <-to

Answer (score 0):

**If you can live with a space before the first word**, then this solution worked for me.

I used the following with the **Regular Expression** radio button checked.:

Find what: `([A-Z])`
Replace With:  `\1`

Note the **leading space** before the `\1` in the replace

[image]

Comment: This will add a space before the first character of the string, this is not wanted.

Comment: Good point it will. That was not a problem for me as I can trim that off afterwards.  I'll update my answer to include that caveat.